# How to locate and invoke controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I just started learning MVC3 today, so please forgive any stupidity (particularly a poorly named title).

This URL doesn't work:

```
.../Test
```

But this one does:

```
.../Index
```

Here's my code:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public static class MyExt
{
    public static ActionResult Test(this MyController test)
    {
        return test.Index();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why you want the Test ActionResult as an extension method?

Comment: why do you need extension method? Routing and its regestration details are in global.asax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extension method won't work because `ControllerActionInvoker` only invokes methods of a controller. You can read more about ASP.NET MVC pipeline [here](http://blog.codeville.net/2007/11/20/aspnet-mvc-pipeline-lifecycle/).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that the MVC plumbing will be able to "see" the extension method Test in order to auto-magically map it using the default routing tables.  MVC uses a convention-based approach.  It thinks all controllers are in specific spots and the like.  Likely it won't think to look for an extension method.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the same result you would be better off setting a new route in your global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Test",
    "Home/Test",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

If you want to have the same for all controllers

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Test",
    "{controller}/Test",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Sorry, but I still can't figure out what you are trying to achieve here

Checkout the following link for an overview on routing:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs